# Cannot use ant layout slider collapsable with SSR with NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I'm using antd within my NextJs app. I placed a Layout component at the top level of my app.

```
/* _app.tsx */
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SideMenuLayout>
        <div>Patate</div>
      </SideMenuLayout>
    </Provider>
  );
}

/* sideMenuLayout.tsx */
const SideMenuLayout = ({ children }: SideMenuLayoutProps) => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const { Sider } = Layout;

  return (
    <Layout style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
      <Sider collapsible collapsed={collapsed} onCollapse={setCollapsed}>
        <div className="logo" />
        <Menu theme="dark" defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]} mode="inline">
          <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<DesktopOutlined />}>
            Play
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      </Sider>
      <Layout className="site-layout">{children}</Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

I get the error "Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server".

I understand <sider collapsible... use this useLayoutEffect. I don't understand why default mode is SSR in my case. I'm not sure how I should proceed if I wanna keep the sider collapsable.

Thanks!

Comment: This open [antd issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/30396) might relate to your problem

Comment: This second ```<Layout className="site-layout">{children}</Layout>``` why not change it to ```Content```?
You know you can always define your Layout like this ```const { Header, Content, Sider } = Layout;```

Comment: You can try dynamically importing the `Sider` component with `next/dynamic` on the client-side only with `{ ssr: false}`.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace component**

Try to wrap antd `Slider` component with condition check, if it is browser pass antd slider otherwise a mocked one. Ideally, you should match the HTML structure of the `Slider` component with your fake slider.

```js
import {Sider as AntSlider} = from 'antd'

export const Sider = props => (
  typeof window === `undefined`
    ? <div {...props}/>
    : <AntSlider {...props}/>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Next.js` attempts to [pre-render](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering) your pages, `useEffect` is an indicator of client-side code.

However, is interesting how `useLayoutEffect` is notified as a warning without more details. Since it is omitted on the server pre-render as `useEffect` is, having this call skipped on the server-side may affect the pre-rendered version of the component. For example, the absolute positioning of an element in the center of a screen depends on screen size, and will not produce the desired result via pre-render.

Perhaps, indicating that your component is dynamic, and not to be considered during the pre-render phase from the get-go is the way-to-go:

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const NossrSider = dynamic(() => {
   const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);
   const { Sider } = Layout;
   return <Sider collapsible collapsed={collapsed} onCollapse={setCollapsed}>
        <div className="logo" />
        <Menu theme="dark" defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]} mode="inline">
          <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<DesktopOutlined />}>
            Play
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      </Sider>
},
 {ssr: false}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the hasSider attribute to the [Layout](https://ant.design/components/layout/#Layout.Sider%3E)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31861229)